# linq to sql group by having

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

Could any one show my how to write query using linq to sql to 
search for suburbs which have at least 1 venue in specific state

Location

```
SuburbID
SuburbName
StateName
```

Venue

```
VenueID
VenueName
SuburbName
StateName
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var locations = from loc 
                in dataContext.Locations 
                where loc.Venues.Count > 1 
                select loc
```

EDIT: Final answer:

If you have the foreign keys setup between Location/Venue:

```
string stateName = "New York";  

var locations = from loc 
                in dataContext.Locations 
                where loc.Venues.Count > 1 && loc.StateName == stateName 
                select loc;
```

---

If there isn't a foreign key relationship:

```
string stateName = "New York";

var locations = (from v 
                 in dataContext.Venues 
                 where v.StateName == stateName 
                 select (from l 
                         in dataContext.Locations 
                         where l.SuburbName == v.SuburbName && l.StateName == v.Statename              
                         select l
                        ).Single()).Distinct();
```

---

Really though, you should fix your tables.  The Venue table should have a suburbID instead of "StateName" and "SuburbName" - it is redundant to keep both.

Comment: I knew the table should have SuburbID however sometime user may enter suburb that not in the database yet?

Comment: If it isn't in the database yet then add it before inserting the Venue.  Or make the user enter a new suburb before they can add a venue to it.

Comment: Suppose a user fully enters a Venue's information - at that point, you have enough information to store a Suburb. (unless there are fields we don't see).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of simple answers:

```
var suburbNames = dataContext.Venues
  .Where(v => v.StateName == specificState)
  .GroupBy(v => v.SuburbName)
  .Select(g => g.Key)

           //

var locations = dataContext.Location
  .Where(loc => loc.StateName == specificState)
  .Where(loc => loc.Venues.Any())
```

With that Venues property:  you can get that by adding the relationship in the linq to sql designer - even if the foreign key doesn't exist / isn't enforced in the database.